# How can I integrate this?(Double integral)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$D= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \vert 0 \leq x \leq y, y^2-x^2 \leq 1, 1 \leq xy \leq 9  \}$

$$\int\int _D (y^2 - x^2)^{xy}(x^2 +y^2)dA$$

---

My friend said this can  be solved by integration by substitution

Put  $u= y^2 -x^2, v= xy$

Then $D$ is a rectangle-shape area like the below in $(u,v)$- axis(please confer below picture.)

[image]

I asked the reason to him why it does be rectangle, but he said "There are 4-intersection points in $(x,y)$- plane, therefore it would be 4 vertex in $(u,v)$-plane, so definetely rectangle. "

But in my thought, though there are 4 points, we can't conclude the boundary line of the area is a straight line. Because the boundary of the D in $(u,v)$ plane could be curves not only for lines. So, Can't conclude the rectangle shape.

So I contradicted his claim and suggest my idea like the above, he said then "I don't know"

So, Is my thought is right? If my friend is right what theorem based that makes his claim right? What is the method for find the above double integral?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the boundary correct or is there a missing comma?

Comment: Yes sorry for missing comma. I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u = y^2-x^2\\
v = xy$

$1\le xy \le 9$ becomes 
$1\le v \le 9$

The line $x = y$ is one of the lines we find when $x^2 - y^2 = 0$ or $u=0$

$y^2 - x^2 = 1$ becomes $u=1$

Jacobian:

$du\ dv = \det\begin{bmatrix} \frac {dv}{dx}&\frac {dv}{dy}\\\frac{du}{dx}& \frac{du}{dy}\end{bmatrix} \ dx\ dy$

$du\ dv = \det\begin{bmatrix} y&x\\-2x& 2y\end{bmatrix} \ dx\ dy\\
du\ dv = 2(x^2+y^2)\ dy\ dx$

After the transformation we have:

$\frac 12\int_0^1\int_1^9 u^v \ dv\ du$

Comment: If we integrate out $u$ first, $\int_0^1u^vdu=\frac{1}{v+1}$, so the result is $\frac12\int_1^9\frac{dv}{v+1}=\frac12\ln5$.